# Map base class to specific implementation for collections

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is it possible to map from a source-object to a specific implementation of a target object using automapper?

In the following code-sample, I want to map from `SourceItem` to `TargetSampleItem` and not to `TargetBaseItem`. Important: `TargetBaseItem` can't be abstract. But if I use the following mapper-configuration, always `TargetBaseItem` is used.

To summarize things up, the following collection should contain items of type `TargetSampleItem`, which is derriving from `TargetBaseItem`:

```
public IList<TargetItemBase> Items { get; set; } = new List<TargetItemBase>();
```

Complete code

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MapperTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<SourceRoot, TargetRoot>();

                cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, TargetItemBase>()
                    .IncludeAllDerived();
            });

            configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

            var source = new SourceRoot
            {
                Id = 1,
                Items = new List<SourceItem>
                {
                    new SourceItem { A = "a1", B = "b1" },
                    new SourceItem { A = "a2", B = "b2" }
                }
            };

            var result = mapper.Map<TargetRoot>(source);

            // Should retur true
            Console.WriteLine(result.Items.First() is TargetSampleItem);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Source model
        /// </summary>
        public class SourceRoot
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public IList<SourceItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<SourceItem>();
        }

        public class SourceItem
        {
            public string A { get; set; }
            public string B { get; set; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Target model
        /// </summary>
        public class TargetRoot
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public IList<TargetItemBase> Items { get; set; } = new List<TargetItemBase>();
        }

        public class TargetItemBase
        {
            public string A { get; set; }
        }

        public class TargetSampleItem : TargetItemBase
        {
            public string B { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

using `As<>` is not working, because than AutoMapper is not mapping to the type, rather than just casting it:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, TargetItemBase>()
   .As<TargetSampleItem>();
```

**EDIT 2/Solution**

Using `As<>` **is working**, if a map between `SourceItem` and `TargetSampleItem` is added too:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, TargetItemBase>().As<TargetSampleItem>();
cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, TargetSampleItem>();
```

Comment: I don't understand, if you are creating the map between `SourceItem` and `TargetItemBase`, why would AutoMapper create an instance of TargetSampleItem?

Comment: Good point, I tried to enforce this by using Include<> but could not find any working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`As`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html#as) does work for me:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, TargetItemBase>().As<TargetSampleItem>();
cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, TargetSampleItem>();
```

Comment: Great, this is working. This was not working for me previously, because I've forgotten the second map: `cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, TargetSampleItem>();`

Answer (score 1):

If `As<>` doesn't work for you, then a possible solution might be using `AfterMap` like -

```cs
CreateMap<SourceRoot, TargetRoot>()
    .AfterMap((s, d) =>
    {
        s.Items.ToList().ForEach(p => d.TargetItems.Add(new TargetSampleItem { A = p.A, B = p.B }));
    });
```

(Its not an elegant solution, but since `TargetSampleItem` is not the target of any of your maps, I don't see any reason why AutoMapper would create an instance of it).

You have to rename either of the `Items` properties so that AutoMapper doesn't try to map them automatically (I renamed the one in `TargetRoot` class to `TargetItems`). And of course you don't need the mapping between `SourceItem` and `TargetItemBase`.